# Join query with JPA?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, join, playframework

I'm having a hard time with this join query in my application. I have two classes, `Encounter` and `CheckedEncounter`. `CheckedEncounter` is a temporary model that I'm using to manage the `Encounters` that have already been processed. It looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class CheckedEncounters extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ce_id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name="ce_encounter")
    @OneToOne
    public Encounter encounter;

    @Column(name="ce_synced")
    public boolean synchronised;

}
```

What I want to do is select every Encounter, that was created for a specific user and which has no CheckedEncounters record yet (so only the ones that can't be found inside CheckedEncounters tabel)

With this line I'm selecting all my encounters for my specific user:

```
List<Encounter> encounterRequess = Encounter.find("byTargetUser", myuser).fetch();
```

**Edit:**

```
public static List<Encounter> getNewEncountersByTargetUser(User targetUser){
    return Encounter.find("from Encounter as enc " +
            "where not exists ( " +
            "from CheckedEncounter as cenc " +
            "where cenc.encounter = enc)" +
            "and enc.targetUser = ?", targetUser).fetch();
}
```

I tried it with the query marc suggested but It's giving me an error:

```
Execution exception
IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CheckedEncounter is not mapped [from models.Encounter as enc where not exists ( from CheckedEncounter as cenc where cenc.encounter = enc)and enc.targetUser = ?]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
from Encounter as enc
where not exists (
    from CheckedEncounter as cenc 
    where cenc.encounter = enc
)
```

See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries).

Comment: And where does this return the Encounter list?

Comment: `from Encounter` returns the Encounter list. This is a normal query with a additional condition and can thus be used as e.g. a named query (then you could add an `AND enc.user = :user` or so) or directly executed by the EntityManager.

Comment: So should I have something like `List<Encounter> encounterRequess = from Encounter as enc...` ?

Comment: Oh this is simply an SQL query! I thought it was Java for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly, it is HQL/JPA-QL and looks similar to SQL.

Comment: One more question: is it possible to specify the user as well? or should I just add "user = ?"

Comment: just do `... cenc.encounter = enc) and enc.user = ?`, if the user is a unnamed parameter, els `... and enc.user = :user`.

Comment: Could you take another look at my post please? It's giving me an error saying CheckedEncounter is not mapped. The database table for it does exist, and the relation is there to (OneToOne). Any ideas? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Sled let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1958/discussion-between-marc-and-sled)

Comment: Marc, thanks for your help! The problem was a typo in the table name, it's fixed and working now!